# Jest failing when using react-native scrollables

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

When importing e.g. a FlatList from react-navigation my tests fail, if I import it from react-native it works. My component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from 'react-navigation';

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{item}</Text>
  </View>
);

const MyList = () => (
  <FlatList data={['a', 'b', 'c']} renderItem={renderItem} />
);

export default MyList;
```

and my test looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import MyList from '../MyList';

describe('MyList component', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<MyList />);
    const tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The error message I receive is the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by mocking the scrollables the following way:

```
jest.mock('react-navigation', () => ({
  FlatList: 'FlatList',
}));
```

If you use SectionList and/or ScrollView as well you can add them the same way:

```
jest.mock('react-navigation', () => ({
  ScrollView: 'ScrollView',
  SectionList: 'SectionList',
}));
```